# How to give the desired path of an image?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie in ruby so please ignore my little mistakes ;)
Im trying to show an image in a **View** and everything works fine except the path of the image I gave to img's src attribute, I'm using Rails 4 and as a default web project tree in Rails my project has following directories

**app**

config

db

**public**

and some other…

my image is in **"app\assets\images\file.jpg"**
And i Have coded this line in my html file.

```
<img src="/app/assets/images/file.jpg" alt="image" />
```

But image doesn't load on the page!!!
When I check it in "[firebug](http://getfirebug.com)" I found the request of:

```
"http://localhost:3000/app/assets/images/file.jpg"
```

this request exactly means **"public\app\assets\images\file.jpg"**
and clearly is not my path! and even does not exist.

What should I code for src's value to make it!?

Comment: What is the correct path to the file then?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld this is the correct path "/app/assets/images/file.jpg". But it looks like ruby starts reading my path from directory named "public"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="<%= asset_path("file.jpg") %>" alt="image" />
```

Comment: what about the ones in css? I cannot use ruby methods there!

Comment: Rails is aware of the app/asset/images folder, so you just need to specify the name of the image instead of the actual path in the css files